# Use c# model class in angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, model

Thanks in advance

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-data',
  templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];
  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'weatherforecast').subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
interface WeatherForecast {
  date: string;
  temperatureC: number;
  temperatureF: number;
  summary: string;
}
```

In the above code WeatherForecast is an interface defined inside angular .ts file .
How can I use my existing C# model class rather than the interface ?
I am not able to use the using command to add references.
(Sorry if any issue in writing format)

Comment: What you're asking doesn't appear to make sense. They are two different languages. You can't use code from one language in another language. They have different syntax, and totally separate compilers, runtime environments etc. Best you can do is create classes/objects in both languages which match each other in structure, if you need to be able to send data between them in a specific format.

Comment: Hi , Thanks. So do I need to manage multiple models for same data?

Comment: Yes, you do. It's a client-server architecture. Angular is running on the client, C# is running on the server. They are separate pieces of software, running on different machines in different environments, with no link between them, other than the ability to send messages from one to the other (using HTTP, in this case).

Comment: you can share the data via some contract tool like swagger. im not sure what is needed for angular.

Comment: An alternative would be to write a separate C++ or C# node module. Though that usually ends up being more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @stout Do you have any sample code for to write separate C# node module ? Thanks

Comment: @DanielA.White Do you have any reference ? Thanks

Comment: @AfzAl: Below is the link to the blog that taught me the process. In my opinion it's the most clear tutorial for beginners. A good reason why you would want to use a C++ node module is if you need to access the machine itself using unmanaged C++, where Angular, being a webstack technology, would not support that. But if you simply want to use C++ because porting it into TypeScript is a pain, then it's probably the wrong approach, and you should really port it... Link to the tutorial: https://medium.com/jspoint/a-simple-guide-to-load-c-c-code-into-node-js-javascript-applications-3fcccf54fd32

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract your DTO to a separate file
2. Use Typegen https://typegen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html or a similar tool to generate your DTO from annotated C# classes

Comment: That's the only way to share model here. You cannot use exactly the same class in TS, but you can keep your TS interface in sync automatically, so it's actually the same as if you had C# class in TS